# How to redirect a GET request to a POST request in ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, body-parser

I'm making a API for an application. I use NodeJS with expressJS and body-parser. 
My problem is when I'll try to redirect a GET request to a POST request with the method : res.redirect(url), my API doesn't understand the type of the request. My API tries to make a GET request instead of POST request.

How can I specify to my API that I want to redirect to a POST request ? I don't found any response actually on the net.

This is my code :

```js
router.get('/:connectionType/users/:userType/:email/:password/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {

    const service: AuthServices = new AuthServices(connection)

    const { connectionType, userType, email, password } = req.params

    let checkingUser: Promise<any> = service.checkUser(req, res)
        .then(data => {
            if (data[0]){
                let checkingPassword: Promise<any> = service.checkPassword(req, res)
                    .then(data => {

                        const xdata = data[0]

                        xdata
                            ? res.status(200).json({ userID: xdata['userID'] })
                            : res.status(401).json({ error: WRONG_PASSWORD })
                    })
                    .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ error: INTERNAL_ERROR }))
            }
            

            // my probleme is just here
            else if (connectionType === 'signup') {
                const query = stringify({
                    userType,
                    email,
                    password
                })
                // this is my redirect 
                res.redirect(`${ auth }/users?${ query }`)
            }
                

            else
                res.status(401).json({ error: WRONG_EMAIL })
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ error: INTERNAL_ERROR }))
})
```

For my POST request, I choose to use URL's params instead a entire URL like that : router.post(/users/:userType/:email/:password, () => {}).
Even if I choose this kind of URL, the problem stay the same, my API doesn't understand that I want a redirection to a POST.

**EDIT : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect **

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

Comment: And query parameters do not count as posting.

Comment: Oh, ok I understand. That make sense ! Thank you Jonas W.